# Knockout Js, JQuery UI Dialog and Partial view

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, knockout.js, jquery-ui-dialog, asp.net-mvc-partialview

I have a requirement whereby I need to load in Partial View(razor) in Jquery Modal dialog, the problem is I am not able to integrate with Knockout. The implementation will be like this, as a user enters a site, I need to show him a Modal dialog (pop-up -- Partial view) with Knockout binding. Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are going to be showing the dialog immediately one approach you can use is to simply render the Partial View directly to the main page as a template.

You would define your partial view like so:

```
<script id="myPopupTemplate" type="text/html">
   <span data-bind="text: Name"></span>
   <span data-bind="text: Age"></span>
   <button data-bind="click: doSomething">Do Stuff</button>
</script>
```

And in your main page, you simply [render the template](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd492503%28v=vs.108%29.aspx) to the bottom of the page:

```
@Html.RenderPartial("MyPartialView")
```

Now you can use the [template binding](http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/template-binding.html) as you normally would, except this time you can wrap it all in the structure you need for the modal dialog using jQuery.

```
<div data-bind="template: {name: 'myPopupTemplate', data: myData}">
</div>
```